How do stock warrants work and how long do they have to exercise before it becomes worthless?
I am in a difficult financial position. A company has agreed to sell warrants to purchase 3 shares.
The SEC filing was from Marth 18 2024, they proposed it in November 2023
Heres a copy and paste
Closing of Private Placement
As disclosed on UTime Limited’s (the “Company”) Report on Form 6-K (“Form 6-K”)filed with the Securities and Exchange Commission (“SEC”) on November 16, 2023, the Company entered into certain securities purchase agreement (the “SPA”) on November 15, 2023 with certain “non-U.S. Persons” (the “Purchasers”) as defined in Regulation S of the Securities Act of 1933, as amended, pursuant to which the Company agreed to sell an aggregate of 373,846,160 units (the “Units”), each Unit consisting of one ordinary share of the Company, par value $0.0001 per share (“Share”) and a warrant to purchase three Shares (“Warrant”) with an initial exercise price of $0.33 per Share, at a price of $0.13 per Unit, for an aggregate purchase price of approximately $48.6 million (the “Offering”), subject to various conditions to closing.
On March 18, 2024, the transaction contemplated by the SPA consummated when all the closing conditions of the SPA have been satisfied and the Company issued the Units to the Purchasers pursuant to the SPA.
I heard from someone that they can exercise their warrants after waiting 6 months, which is September 18. What happens then?
Does the stock price fall? What happens to the float?
Will the company lose money if they sell under .13 cents? They did a 25 : 1 reverse stock split, so the adjusted price per unit is 3.25.

Why does this put you in "a difficult financial position"? Do you own shares or work for the company?
